# Download hibernate dependencies

Tags: hibernate, maven

I am making a web application with hibernate and maven and I am not able to download the hibernate dependencies.

These are my dependency lines:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- JDBC driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${jdbcDriver.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${jdbcDriver.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${jdbcDriver.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SLF4J (required by Hibernate ) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Javassist (required by Hibernate) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>${javassist.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CGLIB (required by Spring) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servletApi.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Tapestry -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tapestry.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${tapestry.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

I tried mvn eclipse:elicpse and then mvn install -U but I  still getting the following errors for every single code line where a hibernate annotation is included

> [ERROR] \Users\Radorf\workspace\pfcswim\src\main\java\e\v\v\pfcswim\model\user\User.java:[5,24] error: package javax.persistence does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You're obviously missing the JPA annotations. I seem to recall that

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

has `javax.persistence:persistence-api` as transitive dependency. I'm guessing you're missing that one?

Of course you could grab the JPA artifact directly as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or if you'r trying for JPA2:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Cheers,

Comment: Are you sure you obtained the dependency? Check in `~/.m2`. Also see my edited answer. What Hibernate version are you trying for?

Comment: I tried what you posted and still doesnt work. I checked the /.m2 directory and I guess the jar should be at m2\repository\org but I cant find it there, so for whatever reason I am not able to download it.

Comment: I think the error is within the eclipse configuration. It seems like eclipse do not take the maven dependencies. I keep trying things but nothing seems to work